# Should we plan purchase module or inventory first for data warehouse design

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, star-schema-datawarehouse

I have been developing a data warehouse for Analytical needs. As I am a new learner, I have started first working on my own work area of manufacturing related tables and made reports for these. I have been following Kimball design and so adding step by step new processes.
Now, I would like to start working on Inventory or purchase transactions.

I am interested to know, what is the recommended flow of processes for a good data warehouse design, for example should I first work on purchase transactions or Inventory transactions and so on for all other processes. As of now, I would like to consider it for manufacturing organization. Is there anywhere documented such a practice.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: You design the data warehouse to hold the transaction applications that your users demand.  Otherwise, there is no specific order of transaction application design.  A data warehouse is just like a physical warehouse.  You don't fill the warehouse just to fill it.  You fill it with items that sell.  You fill it to empty it.  :-)  A data warehouse is similar.  You fill it so users can answer questions.

Comment: Thanks. I meant, to be able to design well to answer all user queries, what direction we should go, first design purchase model or inventory model? Whats more better ways, or there are no such need to think about. I am about to design anyway both.

Comment: Here's what I do.  Write all the queries first.  Then design the data warehouse.  Then, I decide, will this design answer all of the queries?  If the answer is yes, all queries can be processed, then I implement the data warehouse.